# Play Framework Java - Build nested JSON object for autocomplete

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am new to Java coming over from Python and am trying to figure out how I can loop over a ebean query result set and append data to a JSON object tha will be sent back to an autocomplete widget on the front-end.

I am using the following libraries:

- import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
- import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

Currently the search does work but if there are multiple results I am only getting one, I suspect it is because I am over-writing my JSON object each time through the loop.

Does the .putArray method on the JSON object clear it out each time, and if so how should I go about appending JSON objects to an already present JSON array.

**My autocomplete method:**

```
    @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
    public Result searchContacts(String term) {

    List<Contact> searchedContacts = Contact.find.where().eq("firm_id", session().get("firm")).or(com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like("first_name", "%"+ term + "%"),
            com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like("last_name",  "%" + term + "%")).findList();

    // build result set for autocomplete suggesstions
    ObjectNode suggestion = Json.newObject();

    for (Contact contact: searchedContacts) {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("value", contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName);
        result.put("data", contact.id);

        suggestion.putArray("suggestions").add(result);
    }

    return ok(suggestion);
}
```

JSON structure must be like so:

```
            suggestions: [
            { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
            { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
            { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect all suggestions into some collection i.e. `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode` and then create a JSON object with it, this snippet gives you what you want (of course I assume that your DB query returns valid set of data):

```
public Result searchContacts(String term) {

    List<Contact> searchedContacts = Contact.find.where()
                  .eq("firm_id", session().get("firm"))                                                               
                  .or(com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like("first_name", "%"+ term + "%"),
                  com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like("last_name",  "%" + term + "%"))
                  .findList();

    ArrayNode suggestions = Json.newArray();

    for (Contact contact : searchedContacts) {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("value", contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName);
        result.put("data", contact.id);
        suggestions.add(result);
    }

    ObjectNode output = Json.newObject();
    output.set("suggestions", suggestions);

    return ok(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation, exactly what I was looking for!